# How to define sets of break points in Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, breakpoints

I want to define some sets of break points in Visual studio, so that I can toggle among them.

By a **set**, I mean a collection of break points at certain lines I define. I have many scenarios that I want to toggle among these sets to ease my debugging.

**For example:**

```
Set 1: breakpoints at line 1, line 3, line 5, line 7
Set 2: breakpoints at line 2, line 4, line 6, line 8,
```

Are there any ways to do it in Visual studio (2008 and above are preferred), or are there any add-ins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This feature is available in Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 in the
>   breakpoints window.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293674.aspx

(c) Visual Studio team (Product Team, Microsoft) Nov 21, 2012

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2394909-breakpoint-sets-or-groups-enable-disable-breakp

Also, here is little macro that implements this functionality in Visual Studio 2008. You may just copy it into any module in macros (Tools > Macros > Macro Explorer > right-click any module > Edit > paste there), and then add it as a command to any menu (via Tools > Customize...)

```
Dim savePath = "c:\temp"
Sub SaveBreakpoints()
    Dim fname As String
    Dim lBreakpointsList As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Breakpoint)
    Dim fileList = IO.Directory.GetFiles(savePath)
    Dim lFiles = ""
    For Each lFile In fileList
        lFiles = String.Concat(lFiles, IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(lFile), vbCrLf)
    Next
    fname = InputBox(String.Concat("Existing sets:", vbCrLf, lFiles, vbCrLf, "Name of new set:"), "Save Breakpoints", "1")
    If fname = "" Then
        Return
    End If
    lBreakpointsList = New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Breakpoint)
    For Each lBreakpoint As EnvDTE.Breakpoint In DTE.Debugger.Breakpoints
        lBreakpointsList.Add(New Breakpoint(lBreakpoint.File, lBreakpoint.FileLine, lBreakpoint.Condition))
    Next

    Using fs As New IO.StreamWriter(String.Concat("c:\temp\", fname, ".txt"))
        For Each lBreakpoint As Breakpoint In lBreakpointsList
            fs.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}   |||   {1}   |||   {2}", lBreakpoint.File, lBreakpoint.Line, lBreakpoint.Condition))
        Next
    End Using
End Sub

Sub RestoreBreakpoints()
    Dim fname As String
    Dim lBreakpointsList As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Breakpoint)
    Dim lProperties As String()
    Dim fileList = IO.Directory.GetFiles(savePath)
    Dim lFiles = ""
    For Each lFile In fileList
        lFiles = String.Concat(lFiles, IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(lFile), vbCrLf)
    Next
    fname = InputBox(String.Concat("Enter name of set to restore. Existing sets:", vbCrLf, vbCrLf, lFiles), "Restore Breakpoints", "1")
    If fname = "" Then
        Return
    End If
    lBreakpointsList = New Collections.Generic.List(Of Breakpoint)
    Dim lBp As Breakpoint
    Using fs As New IO.StreamReader(String.Concat("c:\temp\", fname, ".txt"))
        While Not fs.EndOfStream
            lProperties = fs.ReadLine().Split(New String() {"   |||   "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
            lBp = New Breakpoint(lProperties(0), lProperties(1), lProperties(2))
            lBreakpointsList.Add(lBp)
        End While
    End Using
    Try
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.DeleteAllBreakpoints")
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    For Each lBp1 As Breakpoint In lBreakpointsList
        DTE.Debugger.Breakpoints.Add(, lBp1.File, Convert.ToInt32(lBp1.Line), , lBp1.Condition)
    Next
End Sub

Class Breakpoint
    Public File
    Public Line
    Public Condition

    Public Sub New(ByVal pFile, ByVal pLine, ByVal pCondition)
        File = pFile
        Line = pLine
        Condition = pCondition
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the starting of the line. Then Click Breakpoints> Insert Breakpoints. You can do this for every single line. I think thats what you are looking for.

Comment: You seemed to misunderstand my question. I want to ask for a set of breakpoints